# mesh won't deform (in pose mode) once parented to bones

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, rigify

So I followed this tutorial: [riggify](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/04/23/quick-rigging-with-the-rigify-addon/) to the letter and once I go into pose mode, my mesh will not move/deform with the bones. Only the bones move, without any of the mesh. I have tried parenting to just the bones without the riggify and it still doesn't work. Tried looking up solutions but nothing solves it.

here's a link to my .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6xONZ2msgKHRDFDaGNJc2RqaWM/edit?usp=sharing

This link is for AFTER I have applied the parenting (with automatic weights)

Answer (score 2):

Automatic weighting can fail if there's a badly-formed polygons in the mesh. In your case, there are several overlapping vertices in the character's mesh. After executing **Remove Doubles** on the mesh, automatic weighting works as intended.

As an aside, you're not supposed to use the `metarig` object as the character's rig. In the **Property** space > **Object Data** tab (armature icon) for that object, there's a **Generate** button that will create a separate full-featured armature object, named `rig`.

[image: 1a]

The `metarig` is provided as an intuitive way for you to indicate where joints, bones, etc. are supposed to be. The script uses the `metarig` to decide where all the "real" bones and control bones go. That `rig` object generated from the `metarig` is meant to be used as the character's armature, not the `metarig` itself.